# Cassandra - update all records by primary key, mismatched input error

Tags: cassandra

I've recently started using Cassandra and I understand that Cassandra prevents a user from deleting all records in a table by primary key.
As you need to provide all cluster keys as well.

I tried using the standard sql such as:

```
UPDATE my_table SET is_deleted = 'true' WHERE COUNTRY = 'XXX' AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM my_table WHERE COUNTRY = 'XXX');
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
SyntaxException: line 1:113 mismatched input 'SELECT' expecting ')' (... 1 AND user_id IN ([SELECT]...)
```

Please advise.

Comment: What is your table schema ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use nested query in cassandra.**

You have to use two separate query.

First select all `user_id` from `mytable`

```
SELECT user_id FROM mytable WHERE COUNTRY = 'XXX'
```

Second For each user_id found in the previous steps

```
UPDATE my_table SET is_deleted = 'true' WHERE COUNTRY = 'XXX' AND user_id = 'XXX'
```

You can execute the second query using `executeAsync`.

If `user_id` is the partition key, you can also use in query to update but small size of `user_id` list is recommend

```
 UPDATE my_table SET is_deleted = 'true' WHERE COUNTRY = 'XXX' AND user_id in ('XXX', 'XXY', 'XXZ')
```

Comment: So this means I need to save the results of the first query and then use it for the UPDATE query.
What does 'executeAsync' do?

Comment: `executeAsync` will execute query in non-blocking way.  See more https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries